# Taylor series representation as an infinite sum

Tags: series-expansion

I want to see the Taylor series representation for arbitrary functions, e.g. $\sin$. With the `Series[]` command, I can only see the first $n$ terms. Is there the possibility to show the infinite sum representation?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Borrowing from Chip Hurst:

```
f = Inactive[Sum][
  Assuming[n > 0, SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]] x^n, {n, 
   0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

```
ExpToTrig[Activate[f]] // Simplify

(*Sin[x]*)
```

Comment: Your `Assuming[]` does nothing unless there is a `Simplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]` within.

Comment: @J. M. Actually there is a difference (in V10.1): http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwYxv.png. -- Algohi, one can also use `FullSimplify` instead of the `Simplify @ ExpToTrig[..]`.

Comment: @Michael, version 10 is looking weirder to me with each passing day… :o

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did not know that  `FullSimplify` can do that. I checked other examples and `FullSimplify` gives same results as `ExpToTrig`. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}], n >= 0 && n ∈ Integers]
```

> ```
> ((-1)^(1 + n) Sin[n π/2])/n!
> ```

Comment: Bit then I am expressing Sin with another Sin. For Sin(x) I know the Row. I am trying to get some result like:  ` Sum[((-1)^k*x^(2*k + 1))/(2*k + 1)!, {k, 0, Infinity}] ` .

Comment: @McLawrence Yes  you can post code in comments as well: enclose it in single backticks like this: \` <your code> \`