# Taylor series representation function?

Tags: function-construction, summation, series-expansion

Is there a built in Taylor series representation function in Wolfram Mathematica? For Example:

```
In=TaylorSeries[(*function goes here*)]

Out=(*Function rewritten in sigma notation as a power series*)
```

If not, is it possible to code such a thing...? How does it work in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Have you seen `Series[]`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't wrap up the expression into a generalized sigma notation. It shows the expansion.

Comment: So basically you need something that can discern the general form of the n'th derivative of a function in an automated way? This seems really difficult, and in general it seems possibly mainly only with a gigantic look-up table.

Comment: Then, you might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83560).

Comment: I'm still curious how Wolfram Alpha computes all those different series. Specifically the first that appears, it appears as the most compact.

Comment: I found an even better way to do it... Please hold on, and keep this thread active.

Answer (score 0):

An example for sine as a function of x:

```
SeriesRepresentationSin = TraditionalForm[Inactive[Sum][SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, 0, k}, Assumptions -> k >= 0]*x^k, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]] (*Outputs function expression as series*)
Activate[SeriesRepresentationSin] (*Outputs algebraic function expression*)
```

[image]

[image]

I'm still curious of how Wolfram Alpha outputs so many different series. I'm guessing for now it has to do with the "Assumptions" command.

There is also:

```
MathematicalFunctionData["Sin", "SeriesRepresentations", "TraditionalFormPresentation" -> True]
```

[image]

Although it appears to be limited to some known functions, I believe.